# Using pandas for loading huge json files

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-analysis

I am having a 500+ huge json files, each of size 400 MB, when in compressed format(3 Gigs, when uncompressed). I am using standard json library in python 2.7 to process the data, and the time taking for the same is too much and I think `json.loads()` is the major culprit for time consumption. I am thinking of using pandas in python for loading data from the gzip files and doing the analysis.

I just heard about pandas, and am not sure if this is the right tool for using. My concern is, will using pandas,will help me in any substantial improvement in speed?

NB: of course I can parallelise the work and achieve speed, and still I find things pretty much lagging.

Also, will adding data by reading with `gzip.open()` and then converting json to dictionary with `json.loads()` and then storing in sqlite3, would help me in anyway for furthur analysis.

json entry sample:

```
 {"created_at":"Sun Dec 01 01:19:00 +0000 2013","id":406955558441193472,"id_str":"406955558441193472","text":"Todo va a estar bn :D","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/blackberry.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for BlackBerry\u00ae\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":483470963,"id_str":"483470963","name":"katheryn Rodriguez","screen_name":"katheryn_93","location":"","url":null,"description":"No pretendo ser nadie mas y no soy perfecta lo se, tengo muchos errores tambi\u00e9n lo se pero me acepto y me amo como soy.","protected":false,"followers_count":71,"friends_count":64,"listed_count":0,"created_at":"Sun Feb 05 02:04:16 +0000 2012","favourites_count":218,"utc_offset":-21600,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":10407,"lang":"es","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"DBE9ED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000116209016\/ff11dc9f5a2e05d2800a91cff08c2c73.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/378800000736604157\/b6d36df6332a2cacb0d30b5328b668d6_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/483470963\/1385144720","profile_link_color":"9D1DCF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"E6F6F9","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"medium","lang":"es"}
```

and occasionally you can find json entries of kind:

`{"delete":{"status":"id":380315814080937984,"user_id":318430801,"id_str":"380315814080937984","user_id_str":"318430801"}}}`

Comment: This depends very much on what the json files look like. If you could perhaps show what kind of records are in the json, I would be able to comment.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, I have updated the question as per you asked, its basically data from twitter. I am interested to know, any faster ways to process the data like using read_json in pandas, would be of any help.

Comment: I think because of the nesting and the differences between the entries, that a DataFrame is not a good match with this data. You might want to consider using something like MongoDB.

Comment: weirdly json.loads on this string says: `ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 157 (char 156)`

Comment: @AndyHayden, may be some issue happened, while copy pasting, I am getting solution when using json.loads. The only problem is the time factor

Comment: suggest looking into pandas read_json, faster with less overhead than json...

Comment: @AndyHayden I was thinking of trying that only. But I am confused, as chthonicdaemon pointed out, the nested json and two different formats of json. wuldn't those create problems?

Answer (score 0):

3 GB json files will be huge when stored as nested dicts in python, most likely many times larger, hence using a lot of memory. Watch how the memory usage increases during the load of one of these files and you will most likely notice that your machine starts swapping.

You need either to parse each line as json (if they are) or split the files into smaller chunks.

Comment: I am reading line by line only. I am not loading entire file to memory.